# Inserting in database constraint failed

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I have a problem with inserting data into tables. So here is what I'm doing. I'm adding a music album to favorites table, also adding the songs of that album to a different table called songs. So I get this from logCat:

```
04-08 13:19:58.846: E/SQLiteDatabase(6120): Error inserting album_id=1 mp4= mp3=http://nelu.burduja.com/musica/songs_with/with_515c34d1bbde7.mp3 title=Super hit artist=Gherghe Topa thumb=snwith_515c34d1aeee1.jpeg
04-08 13:19:58.846: E/SQLiteDatabase(6120): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
04-08 13:19:58.846: E/SQLiteDatabase(6120):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_executeInsert(Native Method)
04-08 13:19:58.846: E/SQLiteDatabase(6120):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:113)
04-08 13:19:58.846: E/SQLiteDatabase(6120):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1718)
04-08 13:19:58.846: E/SQLiteDatabase(6120):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1591)
04-08 13:19:58.846: E/SQLiteDatabase(6120):     at com.myapp.functions.DatabaseHelper.addSongs(DatabaseHelper.java:179)
04-08 13:19:58.846: E/SQLiteDatabase(6120):     at com.myapp.functions.DatabaseHelper.addFavorite(DatabaseHelper.java:215)
04-08 13:19:58.846: E/SQLiteDatabase(6120):     at com.myapp.functions.AlbumLazyAdapter$1.onClick(AlbumLazyAdapter.java:94)
04-08 13:19:58.846: E/SQLiteDatabase(6120):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
04-08 13:19:58.846: E/SQLiteDatabase(6120):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
04-08 13:19:58.846: E/SQLiteDatabase(6120):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-08 13:19:58.846: E/SQLiteDatabase(6120):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-08 13:19:58.846: E/SQLiteDatabase(6120):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-08 13:19:58.846: E/SQLiteDatabase(6120):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4440)
04-08 13:19:58.846: E/SQLiteDatabase(6120):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-08 13:19:58.846: E/SQLiteDatabase(6120):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-08 13:19:58.846: E/SQLiteDatabase(6120):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
04-08 13:19:58.846: E/SQLiteDatabase(6120):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
04-08 13:19:58.846: E/SQLiteDatabase(6120):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Firstly I insert an album:

```
public void addFavorite(Albums album) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ALB_GENRE, album.getTAG_GENRE());
        values.put(ALB_ID, album.getTAG_ID());
        values.put(ALB_MIX, album.getTAG_MIX());
        values.put(ALB_NAME, album.getTAG_NAME());
        values.put(ALB_SINGER, album.getTAG_SINGER());
        values.put(ALB_THUMB, album.getTAG_THUMB());
        // Inserting Row
        addSongs(album.getSongs(), album.getTAG_ID());
        database.insert(TABLE_FAVORITES, null, values);

    }
```

then i insert songs from that album via:

```
public void addSongs(ArrayList<Songs> arrayList, String albumID) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
            values.put("title", arrayList.get(i).getSONG_TITLE());
            values.put("artist", arrayList.get(i).getSONG_ARTIST());
            values.put("mp3", arrayList.get(i).getSONG_MP3());
            values.put("mp4", arrayList.get(i).getSONG_MP4());
            values.put("thumb", arrayList.get(i).getSONG_THUMB());
            values.put("album_id", albumID);
            database.insert("songs", null, values);
        }
    }
```

And finally my table queries:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SONGS = "create table "
            + TABLE_SONGS + "(title text "
            + ", artist text, mp3 text, mp4 text, thumb text,"
            + " album_id text REFERENCES " + TABLE_FAVORITES + "(id));";

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
            + TABLE_FAVORITES + "(" + ALB_ID + " text primary key, " + ALB_NAME
            + " text, " + ALB_SINGER + " text, " + ALB_GENRE + " text, "
            + ALB_MIX + " text, " + ALB_THUMB + " text" + ");";
```

So can anybody help me!?

Comment: What is the value of `ALB_ID`?

Comment: @laalto calue of `ALB_ID` is 1

Comment: in ur db your are using two types of constraints first one is Table _properties ALB_ID is primary key and TABLE_SONGS album_id is foreign key so Alb_id is always unique ant not null ,album_id reference from parent table check album_id is available or not in parent table

Comment: @BozidarPrcovski not the integer value in the column but the value of string constant `ALB_ID` you use in your `create table`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing?

You try to insert songs before FAVORITES?
And songs should reference not existing FAVORITE?

Change the order...

From

```
    addSongs(album.getSongs(), album.getTAG_ID());
    database.insert(TABLE_FAVORITES, null, values);
```

To

```
    database.insert(TABLE_FAVORITES, null, values);
    addSongs(album.getSongs(), album.getTAG_ID());
```

---

Start using **AUTOINCREMENT**. 
I don't know where did you take values for `album.getTAG_ID()` but your solution is wrong in any case. Should be changed to something similar:

```
    final long id = database.insert(TABLE_FAVORITES, null, values);
    addSongs(album.getSongs(), id);
```

And table:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
        + TABLE_FAVORITES + "(" + ALB_ID + " INTEGER primary key AUTOINCREMENT, " + ALB_NAME
        + " text, " + ALB_SINGER + " text, " + ALB_GENRE + " text, "
        + ALB_MIX + " text, " + ALB_THUMB + " text" + ");";
```

And method signature of course:

```
public void addSongs(ArrayList<Songs> arrayList, long albumID)...
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you didnot pass a null value into a column that you declare as not null

Comment: @Arun C Thomas I think I pass a null value but i have not declared not null in the table query. Can that be the problem?

Comment: also  make sure that  you clear the tables before inserting the new one because duplicate primary key can also cause this error  So try uninstall the app and re install it.

Answer (score 0):

Ha, you've missed something really important, the base column _ID !
This must be INTEGER and NOT NULL. You can also assign it to AUTOINCREMENT.

Please view this site: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html (Android developer guide about SQlite Databases)

And, this tutorial may also help you: 
Part 1: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/25/get-started-developing-for-android-with-eclipse/

Part 2: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/03/28/get-started-developing-for-android-with-eclipse-reloaded/